# Get error 404 page not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404

My site running yesterday very well but suddenly today get "404 page not found" error. My site developed in Ruby-on-Rails and MySQL database.

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Why do I got this error? Its server issue or any code issue on server?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the /some_controller resource directly if you point your browser to it? The same holds true for your CSS files. Can you post a snippet of the HTML source that includes a the HREF's or the SRC's for your links/CSS?

Edit...

Now that I look at that rewrite rule, of course it doesn't work.

```
^/?$
```

That's only going to match a URL at /. Change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:12007/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

And it should tick. Note that the above will proxy all requests to Rails. You should probably host your media outside of Rails' control, but that's an exercise for the reader.

Source: [Ruby on Rails application only works if the address contains the port](https://serverfault.com/questions/123122/my-ruby-on-rails-application-only-works-if-the-address-contains-the-port)